# Scheme: Iterate Through Whole List

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a program that takes in an input like '((1 plus 2) (2 times 2)). However, when I run that example input, it only prints out '(3). How can I change this code to parse through the whole list that I give it and not just the first instance in the list?

```
(define math
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond [(null? lst) lst]
          [(equal? (second (car lst)) 'plus) (cons (+ (first (car lst)) (third (car lst))) '())]
          [(equal? (second (car lst)) 'times) (cons (* (first (car lst)) (third (car lst))) '())])
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to advance the recursion, so the procedure will continue with the rest of the expressions in the list. Try this:

```
(define math
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond [(null? lst) lst]
          [(equal? (second (car lst)) 'plus)
           (cons (+ (first (car lst)) (third (car lst)))
                 (math (cdr lst)))] ; advance the recursion
          [(equal? (second (car lst)) 'times)
           (cons (* (first (car lst)) (third (car lst)))
                 (math (cdr lst)))]))) ; advance the recursion
```

It works as expected:

```
(math '((1 plus 2) (2 times 2)))
=> '(3 4)
```